# OpenCV en google colab Python con Vídeo

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

En este cachito de código quería redimensionar un vídeo que tengo en Google Drive (este.mp4)
Me da error de que "frame" no se puede "resize" ya que es un NoneValue. Sin embargo ya he comprobado que la ruta del vídeo es la correcta y "frame" no está vacío.

De hecho, si cambio im_show(frame) a dentro del bucle, se me imprimen los fotogramas del vídeo sin problema, pero al ponerlo fuera me da el error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip'   y    error: opencv(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)    



cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/este.mp4')


while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False: break 
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (100,300))

cv2_imshow(frame)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Eso ocurre por que cuando se cumple la condición `ret==False` lo que retorna `cap.read()` sería `None` para `frame`. La solución podría ser crear una variable auxiliar que se modifique luego de la condición, pero en ese caso solo se te mostrará el último frame del video.